# How can I add a car to a user with Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-rest-framework

When i try to add a Car for my user this is what's happening

```
 "username": [
"A user with that username already exists."]
```

This is my models I'm using  Django auth User model 
There are my models

```
class Car(models.Model): 
"""
CAR Table with a ForeingKey from USER Table

"""
user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='cars')
model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
year = models.IntegerField()
seats = models.IntegerField()


def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%d: %s: %s: %d' % (self.id, self.model, self.color, self.year)
```

My Serializers

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Car
    fields = (
        'model', 
        'color', 
        'seats'
        )      

class AddCarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
car = CarSerializer()
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = (
        'username',
        'car'
        )
```

this is my View

```
class AddCarForUser(APIView):
authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

def put(self, request):
    car = AddCarSerializer(data = request.data)
    car.is_valid(raise_exception = True)
    car.save()
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

And this is what i'm sending in a Put Request

```
{
"username": "root",
"car": {
    "model": "Seat Ibiza",
    "color": "Verde",
    "seats": "4" 
}}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `username` need to be inside the `car` element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't works because you use `serializer.ModelSerializer` and the `username` attribute of the`User` class must be unique, that why It can't validate it. To overcome this, follow these steps.

1. Update your serializer `AddCarSerializer`. We add a custom field `username` to handle username passed without a unique, just a simple `CharField`. And we add `create` function because Nested Serializer can't handle creation or update out the box:

```python
class AddCarSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    # add username custom field
    username = serializers.CharField()
    car = CarSerializer()

    class Meta():
        fields = (
            'username',
            'car'
        )

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """ Add car to an user
        """
        tmp_car = validated_data.pop('car')
            user = User.objects.get(username=validated_data['username'])
        car = Car.objects.create(
            user=user,
            model=tmp_car['model'],
            color=tmp_car['color'],
            seats=tmp_car['seats'],
        )

        return car
```

2. update your view :

```python
class AddCarForUser(APIView):

    def put(self, request):
        serializer = AddCarSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

3. update your `Car` model, because `year` attribute doesn't exist when we add a car to an user then, add `null=True` :

```python
class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='cars')
    model = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    year = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    seats = models.IntegerField()
```

And it should work. Don't forget to handle error like if the username passed doesn't exist.

Comment: Luis it worked and the Car was created in the Database but i receive this error AttributeError at /login/addcar/
Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `username` on serializer `AddCarSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `Car` instance.
Original exception text was: 'Car' object has no attribute 'username'.

Comment: I checked your code and it works on my computer. Try to temporarily comment `authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)` If the car is added to the user, it's an other problem.

Comment: You had this error when you sumbit data? why the url is `/login/addcar` ?

Comment: I saw `url(r'^addcar/', views.AddCarForUser.as_view()),`, then why there is a `/login/` before? Did you add something to the `AddCarForUser` view?

Comment: could you come to the chat?

Comment: What do you use to send data? DRF user interface?

Comment: MAN THANK YOU I ONLY ERASE IN THE RESPONSE THE serialized.data form Response(serialized.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED) because we don't have a username to retrieve in CAR model

Comment: yes, Thank you the error was because when you want to serialize.data to the Response throws the error when try to serialize 'username' from the car object that you receive from the AddCarSerializer, that's why I erased it from the method